# Mavenize Grails project not works in STS

Tags: maven, grails, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS 3.6.1, Java 7, Grails 2.4.3.

When create a normal Grails project, it works good. However, my Grails project need to depends on other java projects, so I convert it to maven project. After that STS prompt error

```
Could not find the grails dependency file. This probably means that there is a bad dependency in the pom file.
java.lang.Exception
```

The maven grails project can be build in grails command.

How to resolve is issue? Or if there is walk around to let grails project depends on other Java project.